# How to pass and call a function name as a variable

Tags: python

Is there a way to pass function name as a variable and call it as a fucntion. For example, converting a tuple to a list by passing `list` as a variable:

```
l=(1,2)
x=list
b=%s(l)%(x) #list(l)
```

edited

Sorry for giving you only half of the problem. A user inputs the function name like this

```
l=(1,2) 
f=raw_input("Enter the name:")  
len(f(l))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with `b=%s(l)%(x)`. But you could do `x(l)`.

Comment: `b = x(l)` is the easy way.  You don't need the name of the function to call it; you just need the function itself.  Since you say `x=list`, `x` now refers to that function, so you can use `x(l)` just like that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can assign a function name to a variable and then call it as a function:

```
l = (1,2)
x = list
answer = x(l)
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

If your variable is a *string* representing a name, you can look it up using `globals`:

```
x_name = 'list'
x = globals()[x_name]
y = x((1,2))
```

In the latter case, you can also use `eval`, but it isn't recommended, because *eval is evil*.

(Note that `list` is a type, not a function, but is callable nevertheless, so it works.)